# Can I use Adorner for my Auto Complete WPF Custom Texbox Component

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

I have created a custom WPF Component. It is a auto complete textbox. Internally the component consist of a textbox and a combobox. I'm having some problem with the component.

There are some user experience issue like focusing, hiding dropdown. Overall the user experience is not so good. I have also tried with listbox implementation instead of combobox. I was not satisfied with that also. Later on I have placed the listbox over a popup. Even popup has several issues.

One of my senior was asking me to look on the adorners. He suggested me, adorner can be an option in this context.

So, I'm requesting for some information from experts whether arorner will be  a right choice for me in this current context or not.

Comment: I do not understand the question. What exactly are you asking? Did your senior give any direction on how an adorner would help, or was it a throw away kind of comment (oh I saw this cool pattern...maybe it would help)?

Comment: @Aron. Which point you have not understood ? I think I have clearly explained it.

Comment: @Jimcarry I can see what you're trying to acheive, but as @Aron said, it's unclear what your question is. There is hardly a 'right' choice for creating a `UserControl`, when there are many ways you can go. Sure, `Adorner`s are a great help and could solve your problem. But do you want to know what `Adorner`s are? How you add them to your `Control`? How to style them? How to trigger them? How to layout them? I don't think that your senior lead you completely wrong. I suggest adding an `Adorner` to your `Control` and come back with a more specific question if you run into any trouble.

Comment: @Physikbuddha: I appreciate your answer. Yes there need a learning curve for Adorner. I have shared my previous implementation experience so that other can suggest me whether it will be a right choice or not. That's all. But yes at the end I need to explore it by myself.

Comment: Then I would say, yes, `Adorner`s are a way to solve your problem. As far as I know, the `ComboBox` you have been using previously also uses an `Adorner` to create the dropdown.